# How to resolve Workday Composite Report error: Encountered unexpected error joiningBusinessObject cannot be null

Tags: reporting, composite, workday-api

I hope to ask a question about composite report building.

Context: I am building a composite report showing the number of leavers and active headcount by Country. So far, I have a matrix report as sub-report, showing the number of leavers of a certain month, grouped by Country field. I am using All Active and Terminated Worker Data Source (BO is Worker) for that sub-report.

Issue: When I add that sub-report into my composite report column, I always receive this Page Error message: "Encountered unexpected error joiningBusinessObject cannot be null while building Market on your report. Please fix it and try again." I have made sure that my control field has BO as Worker, Display Field Override as Country and there is no blank field in my sub-report. I don't know what else to do to fix this issue.

Hope you can give me some advice and thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the root cause of my problem. It is because I did not select a Business Object at the beginning; and so even if I define one in my Control Field again and again, this "Encountered unexpected error joiningBusinessObject cannot be null while building Market on your report. Please fix it and try again." error will always be there. However, one thing I find weird is that Workday allows me to proceed to report editing without making the BO defining step mandatory.